# Python using matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to share a Python3.3 tool, which for development convenience is split in variuos files/modules; these modules use tkinter, numpy-1.7.0rc1 and matplotlib-1.2.0.
My questions is:

is there a way to assemble these files/modules into a single self-standing executable file/script, freeing the not skilled user from installing tkinter, numpy and matplotlib, but only having the python3.3 interpreter installed (default in Ubuntu 13)?

Comment: I would rather install the above modules which will only take a couple of minutes rather than "assembling" them

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a freezer like:

- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Both are multi-platform (I do however only Windows, which should be the hardest target for freezing). Im my opinion [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is more complete/more actively developed in regard to packages with binary/data file dependencies but is rather non-standard if your own package contains data/binaries (write `.spec` files or hook files). [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on the other hand is more standard (write a setup script based on setuptools).

As far as I experienced, both handle the nasty parts of matplotlib and its dependencies well and out of the box (`pytz` could be hairy on cx_Freeze).

Answer (score 0):

include a python requirement file which contains the versions of the packages or the minimal version of it.

see https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html